# HTML TwoButtons that saves and move to the next page and the second saves and clear the form in order to add new data

Tags: php, html, forms

i want to have two buttons in my page that the one saves the data and move to the next page of the site and the other button saves the data and then clear all the fields to enter new data. I did the one button that saves the data and move to the next page but for the second button does not clear the fields but also moves to the next page. How can I fix that?

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    .
    .
    .
    header('Location: education.php');
}
```

My button code is this...

```
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit" />

<input type="submit" value="Add New & Save" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code :**

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
    if($_POST['submitted']=="Next")
    {
        //perform inserting data and redirect
        header('Location: education.php');
    }
    else if($_POST['submitted']=="Add New & Save")
    {

        //Clear all fields of form and save the data.
    }

}
```

And give your submit button same name:

```
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="submitted" />

<input type="submit" value="Add New & Save" name="submitted"/>
```

**OR you can try this also :**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_next']))
{
    //perform inserting data and redirect
    header('Location: education.php');   
}
else if(isset($_POST['submit_new']))
{
    //Clear all fields of form and save the data.      
}
```

And give your submit button different name:

```
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit_next" />

<input type="submit" value="Add New & Save" name="submit_new"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could accomplish what you want is to have the ADD NEW button be a separate form. You can have more than one form on a page. So, remove the 'Add New & Save' button from this form and use the 'Next' button for one form and the 'Add New' button for a second form.

Obviously, you would have to change the header url to the current page url (i.e. header('Location:education.php') would have to be changed to point to the page your forms are on. That will save your data and refresh the page, by invoking it again.

And, you would have to include a conditional statement that would determine which button had been clicked, to determine which page to navigate to.